# How can I stop sending accept-headers?

Tags: wcf, .net-core, http-accept-header

My client send to service Accept-Headers: gzip,deflate and the service is sending gzip to me. So I need stop sending Accept-Headers:gzip, deflate from my side. I am using .Net Core 2.1.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can intercept the message before the client sends it, then remove the header and use the iclientmessageinspector interface.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply. I dont know how I can intercept message. I have this code for send message: `Test.TestClient client = new Test.TestClient();Test.ProcessSendRequest sendReq = new Test.ProcessSendRequest(s);`